# Import error "no module named": When importing dynamic class

Tags: python, python-import

All,

I'm putting together a system that needs to dynamically load modules and then create instances of a class within.

My code is:

```
tokens = os.path.splitext("a.b.c")
try:
    module_str     = str(tokens[0])
    task_class_str = str(tokens[1][1:])             
    module         = __import__(module_str, fromlist=[task_class_str])
    task_class     = getattr(module, task_class_str)
except Exception, e:
    STDOUT.error("Failed to import task module", module=module_str, task_class=task_class_str, exception=e)
    continue

try:
    task       = task_class(task)
except Exception, e:
    STDOUT.error("Failed to create task", task=task, module=module, task_class=task_class, exception=e)
    continue
```

The error is:

```
[ERROR]: 'Failed to create task' task_class=<class a.b.c at 0x7fd3beb13e88> exception=ImportError('No module named c',) task=<d.e instance at 0x25700e0> module=<module 'a.b' from '.../a/b/__init__.pyc'>
```

The definition of class c is contained in `a/b/__init__.py`. Why is it trying to import the class as a module when the logging shows that the class is bound?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the task object with

```
task = task_class(task)
```

task is not initialized. Are you trying to do this instead?:

```
task = task_class()
```

Also you said the definition of c is in "init.py". But they way your code is it reads the file "a.b.py" instead.

Comment: task is initialized outside the snippet. What I don't understand is why it's trying to import a.b.c as a module when an instance of task_class is initialized. According to the error task_class is indeed bound to the class a.b.c located in module a.b...

Answer (score 0):

Ignore question.

The issue was that class c had logic errors in it. When instantiated the constructor failed. It's still not clear why the error reported was about a missing module when there code errors in the class.